# Where should I put game data in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data

In a game I would like to have game constant like items information its image, title, detail, but I don't know where I should keep this kind of information. I read some about core data, but don't know if this is a proper way to keep data like this and if core data is the answer where should I put code to initialize these data because I need to initialize it only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/developing-apps-for-ios-sd/id395631522

^ that should help. However this is on Itunes. If it isn't pulling up Itunes open Itunes, search "IOS" and click on "Developing Apps for IOS" (SD or HD it doesn't matter) these videos are created by Stanford University. Video 12 should help you with this problem

Comment: and Video 11 if you are new to it